# Should I remove listener for SOUND_COMPLETE event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

My application needs to notify UI that sound playback is finished. To accomplish that is attaches listener to the SOUND_COMPLETE event of a SoundChannel object.

Should I remove my SOUND_COMPLETE event listener after event processing is done?

```
private function playbackCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    // Notify UI that playback is done etc
    channel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playbackCompleteHandler);
}
```

Everyone says that we should always remove event listeners so that GC could properly collect objects ('channel' object in this case). But it seems that Adobe doesn't do that in the official documentation [1][2]

[1] http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html
[2] http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d21.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatcher holds listeners, so, if your **dispatcher is long-living**(like Application), you should use **weak listeners**:

`channel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, playbackCompleteHandler,false,0, true)`

last `true` allows your objects to be freed.

If you don't need your temporary objects to process dispatcher's events after you loose all references to temporary objects and until they are collected, you shall remove listeners

Otherwise(when **dispatchers are short-living)**, there is **no need to care about listeners**: if you are listening to something temporary, it will die without any problems.

It seems that your case is the last one, so it's better not to pollute code with meaningless lines.

Comment: http://gingerbinger.com/2010/07/actionscript-3-0-events-the-myth-of-useweakreference/

Answer (score 0):

You're question states my answer for this

> Everyone says that we should always remove event listeners so that GC
>   could properly collect objects

If you are no longer keeping an instance of the [Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) object around; then remove the event listener.  If you will still be using the Sound object; then there is no need to remove the listener.

Comment: I will be using sound object, but won't be using channel object. SOUND_COMPLETE is event of channel object. Looks like I should remove listener anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by "channel" object.  Are you using this class for sound: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/messaging/Channel.html ?

Comment: I mean SoundChannel. var channel:SoundChannel = sound.play();